# Load spark sql script in AWS Glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I have many Spark SQL queries on AWS Athena tables saved as text files. Can I load these text files as string variable and use them as dataframe SQL command in AWS Glue script on dataframes cast from dynamicframes? Assume I can load dynamicframes from Athena tables and register their corresponding dataframes as tempviews in Spark.

This is to reuse complex data transformation developed in Spark SQL in AWS Glue jobs.

Comment: Yes you should be able to use those sql statements in your Glue job.Are you facing any issues?

Comment: Hi, @PrabhakarReddy I am facing an issue! How can I access to the tables inside a Database from Glue DataCatalog via Spark SQL module in Glue job? I opened a question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70652123/is-it-possible-to-access-glue-datacatalog-to-work-with-spark-sql